# Testing Silverlight install detection

Tags: silverlight, testing

I have implemented a silverlight install process inline with the best practive approach described in Microsoft's "Installation Experience White Paper - Apr 2009".

I want to test out the following user scenarios

1. Old version of Silverlight
2. No Silverlight
3. Cross browser

In the past I have seen tools for uninstalling and installing different versions of Flash for this same type of testing. Is there anything like that for Silverlight? I know I can disable the plug ins but that is not the same IMHO

TIA

Pat

Comment: Are you looking to automate the process or just do it manuually?

Comment: I just wanted to do it manually. In the end I just disabled the Plugin in IE. In FF i think I uninstalled it via Control Panel